# Solve: $xu_{xy} + 2yu = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to Solve:
$$xu_{xy} + 2yu = 0$$

so Let,
$$u = F(x)G(y)$$
be its solution.

here,

$$u_{xy} = F^{'}(x)G^{'}(y)$$

using this value in initial equation, we get

$$x F^{'}(x)G^{'}(y) + 2y F(x)G(y) = 0$$

$$\implies \frac{xF^{'}(x)}{F(x)} = -2y\frac{G(y)}{G^{'}(y)}$$

How to proceed onward ?

Comment: Maybe you can use that $f(\log x) = F(x)$ has derivative $f’(\log x)=x F’(x)$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Separation of variables is only for BVPs, not unrestricted PDEs as here. OP is not capturing all solutions.

Comment: right you are @ParclyTaxel; I just wanted to comment on the line OP was going down.

Answer (score 1):

$$x F^{'}(x)G^{'}(y) + 2y F(x)G(y) = 0$$

$$\implies \frac{xF^{'}(x)}{F(x)} = -2y\frac{G(y)}{G^{'}(y)}$$

let

$$\implies \frac{xF^{'}(x)}{F(x)} = -2y\frac{G(y)}{G^{'}(y)} =k$$

so

$$\implies \frac{xF^{'}(x)}{F(x)} = k$$

$$\implies \frac{F^{'}(x)}{F(x)} = \frac{k}{x}$$

Integrating both sides we get

$$log F(x) = k log(x) + log(c)$$

$$\implies {F(x)} = cx e^k$$

similarly

$$G = e^\frac{-y^2}{k}$$

so we get,the required solution is,

$$u = Cxe^k e^\frac{-y^2}{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$xu_{xy}+2yu=0\\
u_{xy}=-\frac{2y}{x}u$$
Consider this more straightforward subtitution first.

Let $u=Ce^{F(x)+G(y)}$,
$$F'(x)G'(y)=-\frac{2y}{x}$$
Let $F'(x)=\frac{k}{x}\implies G'(y)=-\frac{2}{k}y$.

Integrating, we get $F(x)=k\ln|x|$ and $G(y)=-\frac{y^2}{k}$.

So, we get $u=Ce^{k\ln|x|-\frac{y^2}{k}}=Cx^ke^{-\frac{y^2}{k}}$.

To apply this to your answer, notice that:
$$\frac{xF'(x)}{F(x)}=-\frac{2yG(y)}{G'(y)}$$
is equivalent to:
$$x(\ln F)'=-\frac{2y}{(\ln G)'}$$
Then, you let $F(x)=e^{F_0(x)}$ and $G(y)=e^{G_0(y)}$, to get the same result we had above.